# Como instalar o pacote plotKML?

Tags: r, instalador, helper, packages

Quero instalar o seguinte pacote no R 
http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/plotKML/index.html

aparece a seguinte mensagem:

Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘scales’
Além disso: Warning message:
package ‘plotKML’ was built under R version 3.2.2 
Erro: package or namespace load failed for ‘plotKML’

Comment: Aparentemente seu R está desatualizado, tente atualiza-lo. Se ainda tiver o erro do `scales` tente instalar o pacote manualmente (`install.packages("scales")`)

Comment: Que comando você está utilizando para instalar o pacote?

Answer (score 1):

Se você receber uma mensagem de que falta alguma dependência, você pode tentar que todos os pacotes dependentes sejam resolvidos antes da instalação do pacote principal com o comando:

install.packages('plotKML', dependencies = TRUE)